# problems with filestream, streamreader and streamwriter

Tags: c#, file, filestream, streamreader, streamwriter

my first problem comes in the form of if i declare my filestream etc in this manner

```
filestream file;
streamreader file_in;
streamwriter file_out;

try
{
    file = new filestream("data.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
    file_in = new streamreader(file);
    file_out = new streamwriter(file);
}
catch(IOException exc)
{
    Console.WriteLine(exc.Message);
}
```

throws an error which says "use of unassigned local variable", which i find odd because all streams are declared outside of the try block but within the main so they should exist within the main.

my other problem comes in the form that if i remove the try/catch block and just declare the streams as one line (eg: `FileStream file = new FileStream("data.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);`) my reading from file does work however i cannot write to file. my write to file function is as follows:

```
    public bool write_to_file(ref StreamWriter file_out)
    {
        if (this.is_empty == true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("error, there is nothing to write.");
            Console.WriteLine("press any key to continue...");
            Console.ReadKey();
            return false;
        }

        try
        {
            string temp = this.is_empty + "," + this.movie_title + "," + this.year_released + "," + this.publisher + "," +
                this.length + "," + this.acting_rating + "," + this.music_rating + "," + this.cinematography_rating + "," +
                this.plot_rating + "," + this.duration_rating + "," + this.total_rating;
            file_out.WriteLine(temp);
            return true;
        }
        catch (IOException exc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exc.Message);
            Console.WriteLine("press any key to continue...");
            Console.ReadKey();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Any reason you changed `FileStream` to `filestream` ?

Comment: -1, the code you posted (1st part) does __not__ give the error you claim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to assign a value to your variables at the top, even if its just null

```
FileStream   file     = null;
StreamReader file_in  = null;
StreamWriter file_out = null;
```

Comment: thank you, that fixes the try/catch block error, however, my streamwriter still doesn't seem to want to write the appropriate data to the file. could you possibly provide any assistance on that?

Comment: well, as soon as i changed it to that solution, it started working again. so for some unknown reason it must be necessary (and it bugs me that i can't figure it out).

Comment: I'm not sure myself.  @HenkHolterman was correct, my suggestion actually shouldn't be necessary.  Also, your code would benefit from using the idea antisanity submitted.  It's safer and will properly dispose of the IO objects.

Answer (score 4):

Well, they're declared but unassigned... so, either set them to null or just do everything together.

```
try
{
    using(var file = new FileStream("data.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
    using(var file_in = new StreamReader(file))
    using(var file_out = new StreamWriter(file))
    {
        // Do your thing
    }
}
catch
{
    throw;
}
```

Comment: thank you, that fixes the try/catch block error, however, my streamwriter still doesn't seem to want to write the appropriate data to the file. could you possibly provide any assistance on that?

Comment: Okay, show the full text and what you're doing with the reader and writer (and when your other methods are being called).

Answer (score 0):

Before closing the files, try flushing the output streams and files.

```
 file_out.Flush();
 file.Flush(); // may be redundant but won't hurt
```

Comment: thank you, i put a file_out.flush() right after the writeline to force it write whats in the buffer to file and clear the buffer, plus added what you said just before the file closing to be sure and lo and behold it works.

Comment: @DamonSwayn: Cheers! Glad to be of help. Please don't forget to upvote answers that you found useful, and optionally accept the answer that solved your problem!